# How far does this analogy go between smooth manifolds and sufficiently nice topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, smooth-manifolds

In the last few months, I have read parts of the elementary theory of smooth manifolds and also more about general topology. One point made in a number of smooth manifold texts is that there are various key distinguishing features of this theory from general topology or, say, real analytic manifolds such as the existence of bump functions or partitions of unity or the tangent space which allow theorems about smooth maps to have more detail and depth than about topological spaces.

However, I have noticed that at least early on there seems to be a fairly strong analogy between the kinds of results you can prove about them and sufficiently nice topological spaces, say second-countable regular (and thus normal). In the sequel, $X$ will represent either a space of this kind or a smooth manifold depending on context:

**Tieze's Extension Theorem** says every continuous function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ defined on a closed subset $A\subseteq X$ can be extended by some continuous function $\hat{f}:X\to\mathbb{R}$. There are various analogues for manifolds, such as the fact that if $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is an embedded manifold which is closed as a subset then every $f\in C^\infty (M)$ can be extended by some smooth function $\hat{f}\in C^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Relatedly, **Urysohn's Lemma** says that for every pair of disjoint closed subsets $F,G\subseteq X$ there is a continuous function $f:X\to [0,1]$ such that $F\subseteq f^{-1}(0), G\subseteq f^{-1}(1)$. Similarly we get that if $F,G$ are a pair of disjoint closed subsets of the manifold $X$ then there is a smooth function $f:M\to [0,1]$ with the same preimage property.

There are some analogues of **bump functions**. On a smooth manifold $X$, for any point $p\in X$ and open neighbourhood $U\subseteq X$ of $p$ then there exists a smooth function $\chi:X\to[0,1]$ such that $\text{supp}(\chi) \subseteq U, \chi|_V = 1$ where $V$ is some smaller neighbourhood of $p$. Any second-countable regular space is completely regular, meaning that given a point $x\in X$ and an open neighbourhood $U\subseteq X$ there exists a continuous function $f:X\to [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 1$ and $f(y) = 0$ for $y\notin U$ (I don't know if we can manage to get it to be constantly 1 on an open neighbourhood of $x$ but perhaps).

There are additionally versions in both cases of constructing a **partition of unity** subordinate to an open cover.

We can go further: **submersions** and **immersions** on manifolds can be characterised as smooth functions which locally have right or left smooth inverses and we can seemingly take that directly as a definition for topological spaces by replacing "smooth" with "continuous". This might allow us to state/prove various results to do with smooth manifolds that at first glance require the notion of a tangent space to make sense.

My question is therefore a little soft perhaps: **how far does this analogy go? To what extent can we develop the elementary theory of smooth manifolds in a continuous setting?**

A good answer would include a relatively simple case of a result which has no analogue for topological spaces perhaps because it requires some structure that manifolds have and topological spaces fail to have. Perhaps the analogy only seems strong here because all the results use something like second-countability and normality and when we step away from that it breaks down?

Comment: Second countable $T_3$ spaces are separable metrizable spaces

Comment: Actually @Jakobian I wasn't supposing "regular" meant $T_3$ specifically but even if I did and thus got separable metrisable spaces, does that explain everything? Are all separable metrisable spaces essentially manifolds in some continuous sense?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're saying. Topologically, manifolds and separable metric spaces are different. A separable metric space, even if finite-dimensional, can be quite pathological, whereas manifolds are relatively well-behaved

Comment: @Jakobian: I suspected as much. I didn't mean to claim anything, my question was more directed as to why you made the comment above? Does it explain why this analogy seems to work?

Comment: For me it's just a case of things agreeing with each other because both manifolds and separable metric spaces have those type of properties like paracompactness etc. This is my explanation for why the analogy seems to work. I think it's just as simple as that, and as simple as it gets.